# Formatting a longtable

Tags: formatting, longtable

I have a longtable, but I'm unsure how to do two things, listed below.

**NB: The MWE given at the bottom of this post is not an exact representation of how the table appears in my document. This is because I'm using a template, which has many settings. Therefore do not worry about column widths or anything. They appear correctly when I'm using the template but not in the MWE. I'm only concerned about the two issues listed below**.

(1) You'll notice that certain bracketed numbers (...) are right next to the 'bigger' number (for example, look at the 'White' row and 'Academically excluded' column or the 'Mainstream' row and 'Academically Excluded' column). I suspect that that this problem is related to decimal alignment, as the problem only occurs when the bigger number has one number **before** the decimal point. However, I am not unsure how to fix this issue.

(2) An "order" (i.e. I **have** to do it - it is not something I can debate with him) is to have a vertical line/rule between the "Proportion of Individuals in Sample" column and "Graduated" column. I've noted on here that vertical rules are frowned upon here, and shouldn't be used with booktabs, but I don't have any other choice, unfortunately.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.17\textwidth}*{4}{S}}% don't use vertical rules with booktabs (see the documentation)
\caption {Descriptive Statistics (\%): Commerce Faculty ($N = \num{6 508}$)}
    \label{table:DSCF} \\
\toprule
{\bfseries\hskip0pt Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.17\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Proportion of Individuals in Sample} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.15\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Graduated} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.17\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Academically Excluded} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.12\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Censored}\\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    {\bfseries\hskip0pt Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.17\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Proportion of Individuals in Sample} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.15\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Graduated} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.17\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Academically Excluded} & \multicolumn{1}{p{.12\textwidth}}{\bfseries\hskip0pt Censored} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
\bfseries Total & 100.0 & 50.1 \footnotesize{(45.8)} & 7.5 \footnotesize{(14.9)} & 42.4 \footnotesize{(39.3)}  \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Gender\\
Male                 & 52.4 & 49.6 \footnotesize{(44.3)} & 8.7 \footnotesize{(17.3)}  & 41.7 \footnotesize{(38.5)} \\
Female               & 47.6 & 50.7 \footnotesize{(48.0)} & 6.2 \footnotesize{(11.5)} & 43.1 \footnotesize{(40.5)}\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Race\\
White & 40.3 & 59.8 \footnotesize{(58.7)} & 3.0 \footnotesize{(4.6)} & 37.2 \footnotesize{(36.7)}\\
Black & 32.4 & 38.7 \footnotesize{(32.5)} & 13.1 \footnotesize{(26.3)} & 48.2 \footnotesize{(41.2)}\\
Coloured & 13.0 & 49.8 \footnotesize{(44.5)} & 7.4 \footnotesize{(16.1)} & 42.8 \footnotesize{(39.5)}\\
Indian/Asian & 14.3 & 48.9 \footnotesize{(44.6)} & 7.9 \footnotesize{(13.3)} & 43.3 \footnotesize{(42.1)}\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Financial Aid\\
Ineligible for Financial Aid & 82.3 & 52.1 \footnotesize{(48.7)} & 5.5 \footnotesize{(10.6)} & 42.4 \footnotesize{(40.7)} \\
Eligible for Financial Aid & 17.7 & 40.7 \footnotesize{(35.2)} & 17.2 \footnotesize{(30.3)} & 42.1 \footnotesize{(34.5)} \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Programme\\
Mainstream & 76.9 & 55.4 \footnotesize{(51.3)} & 5.7 \footnotesize{(10.8)} & 38.9 \footnotesize{(37.9)} \\
Academic Development & 23.1 & 32.5 \footnotesize{(27.1)} & 13.7 \footnotesize{(28.7)} & 53.8 \footnotesize{(44.2)} \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries English Home Language\\
Yes & 69.3 & 55.1 \footnotesize{(52.8)} & 4.9 \footnotesize{(8.6)} & 39.9 \footnotesize{(38.6)}\\
No & 30.7 & 38.8 \footnotesize{(32.8)} & 13.4 \footnotesize{(26.6)} & 47.8 \footnotesize{(40.6)}\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries School Quintile\\
1 & 0.8 & 34.6 \footnotesize{(26.1)} & 30.8 \footnotesize{(42.6)} & 34.6 \footnotesize{(31.3)} \\
2 & 1.6 & 30.2 \footnotesize{(28.1)} & 16.0 \footnotesize{(35.1)} & 53.8 \footnotesize{(36.8)} \\
3 & 5.0 & 32.0 \footnotesize{(27.7)} & 17.5 \footnotesize{(35.3)} & 50.5 \footnotesize{(37.0)} \\
4 & 4.1 & 37.7 \footnotesize{(29.5)} & 17.7 \footnotesize{(32.0)} & 44.5 \footnotesize{(38.5)} \\
5 & 45.4 & 52.0 \footnotesize{(49.2)} & 6.9 \footnotesize{(12.0)} & 41.1 \footnotesize{(38.9)} \\
Independent  & 43.1 & 52.5 \footnotesize{(50.4)} & 5.3 \footnotesize{(8.6)} & 42.2 \footnotesize{(41.0)} \\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Province}\\
Western Cape & 40.0 & 55.1 \footnotesize{(51.3)} &5.9 \footnotesize{(11.6)} &39.0 \footnotesize{(37.0)}\\
Non-Western Cape & 59.9 & 46.8 \footnotesize{(41.9)} & 8.6 \footnotesize{(17.2)} & 44.6 \footnotesize{(41.0)}\\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Year of First Registration} \\
{2006} & 11.6  & 87.8 \footnotesize{(79.9)} & 11.3 \footnotesize{(18.9)} & 0.9 \footnotesize{(1.2)}\\
{2007} & 11.9 & 88.2 \footnotesize{(79.4)} & 10.1 \footnotesize{(19.2)}   & 1.7 \footnotesize{(1.4)}\\
{2008} & 12.6 & 87.1 \footnotesize{(76.7)} & 10.3 \footnotesize{(20.3)} & 2.6 \footnotesize{(3.0)}\\
{2009} & 11.9 & 80.9 \footnotesize{(64.9)} & 9.7 \footnotesize{(24.9)} & 9.4 \footnotesize{(10.2)}\\
{2010} & 11.1 & 62.6 \footnotesize{(57.5)} & 6.4 \footnotesize{(12.7)} & 31.1 \footnotesize{(29.8)}\\
{2011} & 11.7 & 15.8 \footnotesize{(15.3)} & 7.2 \footnotesize{(12.8)} & 77.0 \footnotesize{(71.9)}\\
{2012} & 14.1 & 0.0 \footnotesize{(0.0)}  & 5.4 \footnotesize{(7.5)} & 94.6 \footnotesize{(92.5)}\\
{2013} & 15.1 & 0.0 \footnotesize{(0.0)} & 1.7 \footnotesize{(3.0)} & 98.3 \footnotesize{(97.0)}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't help you much with Requirement #2, except to suggest that you provide more structure in the header which, hopefully, will make the dreaded vertical rule unnecessary. (If you *must* add the vertical rule, you may want to replace the `\addlinespace` instructions with `[1ex]` so as to avoid gaps in the body of the table.)

Regarding objective #1, I would suggest you set up separate columns for the "regular" numbers and for those in parentheses. This suggestion is similar to the one in the answer provided by David Carlisle, *except* that I suggest using `S` column types for all numeric columns. A moderate advantage of using `S` columns instead of `c` columns for the numbers in parentheses is that numbers will continue to be aligned on the decimal markers.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ 
  >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{.17\textwidth} 
  S 
  *{3}{S[table-format=2.1] >{\footnotesize}S[table-format=3.2,input-symbols=()]} }
\caption {Descriptive Statistics (\%): Commerce Faculty ($N = 6508$)}
\label{table:DSCF} \\
\toprule
{\bfseries Variable} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{.17\textwidth}}{\bfseries Proportions in Sample} & 
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Proportions by Subtype}\\
\cmidrule{3-8}
&&
\multicolumn{2}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Graduated} & \multicolumn{2}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Academically Excluded} & 
\multicolumn{2}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Censored}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
{\bfseries Variable} & 
\multicolumn{1}{C{.17\textwidth}}{\bfseries Proportions in Sample} & 
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\bfseries Proportions by Subtypes}\\
\cmidrule{3-8}
&&
\multicolumn{2}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Graduated} & \multicolumn{2}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Academically Excluded} & 
\multicolumn{2}{C{.19\textwidth}}{\bfseries Censored}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\bfseries Total & 100.0 & 50.1 & (45.8) & 7.5 & (14.9) & 42.4 & (39.3)  \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Gender\\
Male                 & 52.4 & 49.6 & (44.3) & 8.7 & (17.3)  & 41.7 & (38.5) \\
Female               & 47.6 & 50.7 & (48.0) & 6.2 & (11.5) & 43.1 & (40.5)\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Race\\
White & 40.3 & 59.8 & (58.7) & 3.0 & (4.6) & 37.2 & (36.7)\\
Black & 32.4 & 38.7 & (32.5) & 13.1 & (26.3) & 48.2 & (41.2)\\
Coloured & 13.0 & 49.8 & (44.5) & 7.4 & (16.1) & 42.8 & (39.5)\\
Indian/Asian & 14.3 & 48.9 & (44.6) & 7.9 & (13.3) & 43.3 & (42.1)\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Financial Aid\\
Ineligible for Financial Aid & 82.3 & 52.1 & (48.7) & 5.5 & (10.6) & 42.4 & (40.7) \\
Eligible for Financial Aid & 17.7 & 40.7 & (35.2) & 17.2 & (30.3) & 42.1 & (34.5) \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Programme\\
Mainstream & 76.9 & 55.4 & (51.3) & 5.7 & (10.8) & 38.9 & (37.9) \\
Academic Development & 23.1 & 32.5 & (27.1) & 13.7 & (28.7) & 53.8 & (44.2) \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries English Home Language\\
Yes & 69.3 & 55.1 & (52.8) & 4.9 & (8.6) & 39.9 & (38.6)\\
No & 30.7 & 38.8 & (32.8) & 13.4 & (26.6) & 47.8 & (40.6)\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries School Quintile\\
1 & 0.8 & 34.6 & (26.1) & 30.8 & (42.6) & 34.6 & (31.3) \\
2 & 1.6 & 30.2 & (28.1) & 16.0 & (35.1) & 53.8 & (36.8) \\
3 & 5.0 & 32.0 & (27.7) & 17.5 & (35.3) & 50.5 & (37.0) \\
4 & 4.1 & 37.7 & (29.5) & 17.7 & (32.0) & 44.5 & (38.5) \\
5 & 45.4 & 52.0 & (49.2) & 6.9 & (12.0) & 41.1 & (38.9) \\
Independent  & 43.1 & 52.5 & (50.4) & 5.3 & (8.6) & 42.2 & (41.0) \\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Province}\\
Western Cape & 40.0 & 55.1 & (51.3) &5.9 & (11.6) &39.0 & (37.0)\\
Non-Western Cape & 59.9 & 46.8 & (41.9) & 8.6 & (17.2) & 44.6 & (41.0)\\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Year of First Registration} \\
{2006} & 11.6  & 87.8 & (79.9) & 11.3 & (18.9) & 0.9 & (1.2)\\
{2007} & 11.9 & 88.2 & (79.4) & 10.1 & (19.2)   & 1.7 & (1.4)\\
{2008} & 12.6 & 87.1 & (76.7) & 10.3 & (20.3) & 2.6 & (3.0)\\
{2009} & 11.9 & 80.9 & (64.9) & 9.7 & (24.9) & 9.4 & (10.2)\\
{2010} & 11.1 & 62.6 & (57.5) & 6.4 & (12.7) & 31.1 & (29.8)\\
{2011} & 11.7 & 15.8 & (15.3) & 7.2 & (12.8) & 77.0 & (71.9)\\
{2012} & 14.1 & 0.0 & (0.0)  & 5.4 & (7.5) & 94.6 & (92.5)\\
{2013} & 15.1 & 0.0 & (0.0) & 1.7 & (3.0) & 98.3 & (97.0)\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That extra structured heading is an excellent idea. Hopefully I can influence my supervisor that vertical lines are a no-no. What, in your opinion, makes vertical lines a no-no? I know it makes the table look a bit 'ugly', but I am wondering if there is a more concrete reason if my supervisor challenges me on this point.

Comment: @Chris - I'm glad you like the idea of structuring the header some more. :-) (In fact, while you're at it, you may also want to provide some information as to what the small numbers in parentheses represent.) About why vertical rules in a table are poor typographical speaking: Simon Fear -- the author of the `booktabs` package -- wrote that if the pieces of information to the left and right of a vertical rule are truly so different as to require a vertical rule to separate them visually, one should create two entirely separate tables. I tend to agree with this view. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,array}
\begin{document}

%\noindent no

\begin{longtable}{
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}
p{.17\textwidth}S|
*{3}{S@{\,}>\footnotesize c}}% don't use vertical rules with booktabs (see the documentation)
\caption {Descriptive Statistics (\%): Commerce Faculty ($N = \num{6 508}$)}
    \label{table:DSCF} \\
\toprule
{\bfseries\hskip0pt Variable} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{.17\textwidth}|}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Proportion of Individuals in Sample} & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{.15\textwidth}}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Graduated} &
 \multicolumn{2}{p{.17\textwidth}}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Academically Excluded} & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{.12\textwidth}}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Censored}\\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    {\bfseries\hskip0pt Variable} &
 \multicolumn{1}{p{.17\textwidth}|}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Proportion of Individuals in Sample} &
 \multicolumn{2}{p{.15\textwidth}}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Graduated} & 
\multicolumn{2}{p{.17\textwidth}}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Academically Excluded} &
 \multicolumn{2}{p{.12\textwidth}}{\centering\bfseries\hskip0pt Censored} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
\bfseries Total & 100.0 & 50.1&{(45.8)} & 7.5&{(14.9)} & 42.4&{(39.3)}  \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Gender&&&&&&&\\
Male                 & 52.4 & 49.6&{(44.3)} & 8.7&{(17.3)}  & 41.7&{(38.5)} \\
Female               & 47.6 & 50.7&{(48.0)} & 6.2&{(11.5)} & 43.1&{(40.5)}\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Race&&&&&&&\\
White & 40.3 & 59.8&{(58.7)} & 3.0&{(4.6)} & 37.2&{(36.7)}\\
Black & 32.4 & 38.7&{(32.5)} & 13.1&{(26.3)} & 48.2&{(41.2)}\\
Coloured & 13.0 & 49.8&{(44.5)} & 7.4&{(16.1)} & 42.8&{(39.5)}\\
Indian/Asian & 14.3 & 48.9&{(44.6)} & 7.9&{(13.3)} & 43.3&{(42.1)}\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Financial Aid&&&&&&&\\
Ineligible for Financial Aid & 82.3 & 52.1&{(48.7)} & 5.5&{(10.6)} & 42.4&{(40.7)} \\
Eligible for Financial Aid & 17.7 & 40.7&{(35.2)} & 17.2&{(30.3)} & 42.1&{(34.5)} \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries Programme&&&&&&&\\
Mainstream & 76.9 & 55.4&{(51.3)} & 5.7&{(10.8)} & 38.9&{(37.9)} \\
Academic Development & 23.1 & 32.5&{(27.1)} & 13.7&{(28.7)} & 53.8&{(44.2)} \\
\addlinespace
\bfseries English Home Language&&&&&&&\\
Yes & 69.3 & 55.1&{(52.8)} & 4.9&{(8.6)} & 39.9&{(38.6)}\\
No & 30.7 & 38.8&{(32.8)} & 13.4&{(26.6)} & 47.8&{(40.6)}\\
\addlinespace
\bfseries School Quintile&&&&&&&\\
1 & 0.8 & 34.6&{(26.1)} & 30.8&{(42.6)} & 34.6&{(31.3)} \\
2 & 1.6 & 30.2&{(28.1)} & 16.0&{(35.1)} & 53.8&{(36.8)} \\
3 & 5.0 & 32.0&{(27.7)} & 17.5&{(35.3)} & 50.5&{(37.0)} \\
4 & 4.1 & 37.7&{(29.5)} & 17.7&{(32.0)} & 44.5&{(38.5)} \\
5 & 45.4 & 52.0&{(49.2)} & 6.9&{(12.0)} & 41.1&{(38.9)} \\
Independent  & 43.1 & 52.5&{(50.4)} & 5.3&{(8.6)} & 42.2&{(41.0)} \\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Province}&&&&&&&\\
Western Cape & 40.0 & 55.1&{(51.3)} &5.9&{(11.6)} &39.0&{(37.0)}\\
Non-Western Cape & 59.9 & 46.8&{(41.9)} & 8.6&{(17.2)} & 44.6&{(41.0)}\\
\addlinespace
{\bfseries Year of First Registration}&&&&&&&\\
{2006} & 11.6  & 87.8&{(79.9)} & 11.3&{(18.9)} & 0.9&{(1.2)}\\
{2007} & 11.9 & 88.2&{(79.4)} & 10.1&{(19.2)}   & 1.7&{(1.4)}\\
{2008} & 12.6 & 87.1&{(76.7)} & 10.3&{(20.3)} & 2.6&{(3.0)}\\
{2009} & 11.9 & 80.9&{(64.9)} & 9.7&{(24.9)} & 9.4&{(10.2)}\\
{2010} & 11.1 & 62.6&{(57.5)} & 6.4&{(12.7)} & 31.1&{(29.8)}\\
{2011} & 11.7 & 15.8&{(15.3)} & 7.2&{(12.8)} & 77.0&{(71.9)}\\
{2012} & 14.1 & 0.0&{(0.0)}  & 5.4&{(7.5)} & 94.6&{(92.5)}\\
{2013} & 15.1 & 0.0&{(0.0)} & 1.7&{(3.0)} & 98.3&{(97.0)}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```